# jquery ui slider to calculate and then change a value of a Div

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, calculator

I am after this ui slider to update a value based on what the current value is, So currently on http://universitycompare.com I have two sliders on the homepage that have value's to the right of them.

What I would like to do is to have a value above that changes based on the two ucas points added together and then divided by two.

A Quick example would be:

Slide the minimum Slider to 240 and then slide the maximum to 320. The total being 560, this then gets divided by 2 and equals 280.

Then there would be values, where if 280, it would equal ABB, but if it was 320, then it would equal maybe AAB.

---

here is my jQuery that I have done for both sliders and for the total's on the right to change:

```
// JavaScript Document
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    $("#slider").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s2").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s2")
        }
});

$("#slider2").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s3").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s3")
        }
});

});
```

Comment: What have you tried?  There are a ton of examples here: http://jqueryui.com/demos/slider/#event-stop and you can use the stop event to do the calculation.

Comment: @dumdum - problem is I am quite new to jQuery - I will update my answer with my current jQuery for the sliders, Just would like to know where to put the Stop Event, etc.. Just Help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should get you there.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {

    var slider1 = $("#slider").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s2").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s2")
        },
        stop:Calculate
    });

    var slider2 = $("#slider2").slider({
        max: 420,
        min: 0,
        step: 20,
        change: function(event, ui) {
            $("#s3").html(ui.value);    
            $("#s3")
        },
        stop:Calculate

    });

    var div = $('#s4'); //cache this object in a variable if you'll be using it multiple times
    function Calculate(){
        var val1 = slider1.slider('option', 'value');
        var val2 = slider2.slider('option', 'value');

        var finalVal = (val1 + val2) / 2;
        //update the ui
        if (finalVal === 220) { //replace 220 with whatever you're checking
           //if finalVal does equal 220
           div.text('some text to display');
        }else{
           //if finalVal does not equal 220
           div.text('some other text to display');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: I see how this works! And I am getting closer, but what I would like to know is how I would go about changing the div that i have labelled 's4'.

Now I have the calculation value set, I would like it to display the middle value, and then depending on what value that is replace it with something.

Finding this quite difficult to do, But I'll play about.

Comment: a little bit stuck still! But I am going to try all night - jQuery is a tricky one!

Comment: You can do `$('#s4').text('your new text here')`. Check out jquery.com and the documentation to learn how to utilize jquery.

Comment: So can I do something like, if Value = 220 then text is: 'new text' - Is that possible using that what you put above?